# Input type submit with onclick fuction return false does not stop submitting form

Tags: javascript

I have a type "submit" input like this:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" onClick="validation('<?php echo $no_id; ?>',event,this.id); "/>


function validation (no_id) {
     alert("FUNCTION WAS TRIGGERED");
     some code here 
     if (error) return false;
}
```

I can see the alert message but it does not stop the form from submitting.

Comment: Yes but I already add my fix before seeing this SO question. Thank you for informing me too.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just need to add a return keyword in my onClick:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" onClick="return validation('<?php echo $no_id; ?>',event,this.id); "/>
```